# Capacitive distance sensor - humidity influence?

Tags: capacity, humidity

We are using a capacitive sensor to measure displacement (from here: https://www.micro-epsilon.com/displacement-position-sensors/capacitive-sensor/?sLang=en). However, we seem to notice a significant dependence on the humidity of the air on the result (temperature in the room is controlled and almost constant, humidity varies over the year from about 20%-50%).

The obvious cause would be a humidity dependence of the relative permittivity. However, I cannot seem to find any data of this dependence (except some for the static case). On the other hand, this surely has been measured.

So the question is: Is there data available for the humidity dependence of the relatve permittivity of air at frequencies from 20 Hz to e.g. 10 kHz?

Comment: There are capacitive humidity sensors for air. They work on the same principle as your displacement sensor. I think you are going to have to account for air humidity when using your displacement sensor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At around 20 °C, water has a [relative electrical permittivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_permittivity) of about 80. Air is 1 so, any water content *could* be a significant factor in altering the capacitance measured. Given that capacitance is proportional to permittivity there should be a fairly direct link.

I guess all you have to do is calculate the percentage presence of water in a given "air" volume for a certain level of [humidity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humidity). For instance, wiki states this: -

> **A parcel of air near saturation may contain 28 g (0.99
> oz) of water per cubic metre of air at 30 °C (86 °F)**

And, [this document](https://brownell.co.uk/datasheets/basics_humidity.pdf) pretty much shows the same thing (ignore the red lines). At 30 °C and 100% RH, the water content is around 25 g per cubic metre: -

[image]

So, using the above example, 1 cubic metre contains 28 g of water or, as a volume that's 28 ml. And, there's 1,000,000 ml in 1 cubic metre so, as a volume percentage, 28 mg of water per cubic metre is 0.0028%.

Given that the permittivity of water is 80, then the capacitance could increase by 80 x 0.0028% = 0.224%.

But, you may also attract condensation onto your sensor and that will surely make the capacitance sensor read a much higher value.

> *Is there data available for the humidity dependence of the relative
> permittivity of air at frequencies from 20 Hz to e.g. 10 kHz?*

This graph from [here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Dielectric-permittivity-of-water-as-a-function-of-frequency-for-the-temperature-0-100C_fig5_281552350) suggests that you won't get a change in dielectric permittivity of water until you are in the GHz region: -

[image]

And [this graph](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Real-and-imaginary-parts-of-the-complex-permittivity-for-water-at-25C-according-to-the_fig8_44229478) shows that the dielectric permittivity of water is constant down to 1 MHz. I think it's reasonable to assume that it will stay constant down to DC: -

[image]

And this graph [from here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-Debye-model-for-the-dielectric-spectrum-of-water-at-20C-with-e-s-802-04-e_fig5_328925895) pretty much nails it down to about 10 Hz: -

[image]

Comment: (a) So this means I can add relative permittivity with the appropriate volume fraction? 28g=28ml would be for a liquid though, not for vapour? (b) Is there data on how that would depend on frequency?

Comment: 28 g would still translate to a percentage of water as a gas in one cubic metre. As for frequency I don't understand your question? Do you mean how often? @Toffomat

Comment: If you want specific help re the sensor, please link the exact data sheet for the device you are using rather than the ambiguous link in your question.

Comment: (a) But weight-wise, 28 g of water per m^3 would be more like 2.2% (1m^3 of air is about 1220 g). (b) Re frequency: The permittivity is frequency dependent. But maybe that's negligible in the range from static to some 10 kHz (?)

Comment: I'm no expert in physics @Toffomat - if you say that 28 g of water in a cubic metre is more like 2.2% then I believe you. I've added permittivity graphs that show it's constant to about 1 GHz. I'm an electrical engineer trying to help you make sense of things.

Comment: Well, 28g/m^3 is about 2.2% by weight. But anyway, your answer indeed helps, thank you!